# opening multiple json files and reading individually

Tags: python, json

New to python and json. How would you go about opening several json files with "with open", then reading individually. Code below:

```
def read_json_file(filename):
      
    with open("File1location/income","file2location/weather", "file3location/sun", 'r') as fp:
        income = json.loads(fp.read())
    
    return data 
income = read_json_file(income)

print(len(income))
```

I need to print the length of each file, but how would I go about isolating each file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with file paths in Python I highly suggest to use the `pathlib` library and import the `Path` class.

So you need, for instance, a list (or in general an array-like structure) where you have stored all of your json paths. Then you can write something like this:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

json_paths = [Path("Fle1location/income.json") Path("file2location/weather.json"), Path("file3location/sun.json"))]

for path in json_paths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        income = json.load(f)
        print(len(income))
```

The `return` keyword is used when creating functions/methods.

**EDIT**

I edit the snippet above in case you want to write a function:

```py
def main():
    for path in json_paths:
        read_json_file(path)


def read_json_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        income = json.load(f)
        print(len(income))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It is important to remember that it is considered a bad practice to have a function that both returns something and has a side effect (i.e., `print`). A function/method/class should have one single, well defined, responsibility (see Single Responsibility Principle). So in this case I have just added the side effect without returning anything.

Comment: @Nathan I edited the answer with more details in the snippet. I think it should be clear.

Comment: @Nathan I edit the question for  having a function.

Comment: appreciate it, helps

Answer (score 2):

To print the size of your files just do this. There's no need to open or read them:

```
import os 

for file in 'File1location/income', 'File2location/weather', 'File3location/sun':
    print(f'{file} {os.path.getsize(file)} bytes')
```

Answer (score 0):

`open` doesn't let you pass multiple file names - you always open a single file (see the docs for confirmation).

Comment: So I would need to individually follow same process and open each file? I am not able to use as fp for the other 3 uploads as it has already been used? As in with open("File1location/income","file2location/weather", "file3location/sun", 'r') as fp:

Comment: Well yes of course. Do you know how to use loops? None of that code is using FTP, so I don't see how that's relevant (unless you have code that you're not showing).

Comment: thanks,no I don't, I would have to look into it.

Comment: In which case, I'd suggest doing a basic Python tutorial/course to learn basic concepts such as loops and others that you're going to need to write any useful programs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).